# Getting query results with Legato gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-analytics

Trying to get query results from Google Analytics using Legato gem (following a previous recommendation I go there + some research). Seems to be simple to define my query, however I fail to understand how to actually get the results. Reading the readme shows how to build some "building blocks", but I fail to get an object where I can read the results from.

Maybe I missed something, and the query results should be written directly to the model (DB), which is not what I want (I wanted to go over them first). Maybe that's the reason I'm not seeing anything.

So can someone please share an example how to read the results? For example, just print the pageviews to the screen.

Thanks

Comment: OK, after some more trial&errorת I've found the way. Need to call "MyModel".results(profile, <additional parameters) and by converting to an array (.to_a) you can browse the results easily.

Comment: I must say, the documentation for using Legato is awful. I have wasted so much time just trying to it figure out.  Still am.

Comment: I agree. But I must say I've managed to find what I need, some of it by searching for "Garb" examples, which are similar. And for my needs, I found it now to be not-so-complicated. Would you like me to post my example? Also, have you experimented with the GA API explorer first?

Comment: thanks for the insight and yes, that would be great.

Comment: What would you like to see in the docs? Which docs are you using? Have you read the wiki which is recommended at the top of the README? This Quick Start has the answer to your question: https://github.com/tpitale/legato/wiki/Quick-Start

Comment: It was a long time ago, so I don't remember exactly what issues I had (I was also much more 'green' in Ruby at the time), but surly I read the README you referenced. I believe I was missing a usage example, on how to write a full model query and its usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So here's the way I've found to use it:
You create a class that defines the "model" of your query (and like Active-Model returning relations, you can also concatenate here). In this example:

- The model/query check for pageviews & unique-pageviews within the ga:pagePathLevel1 dimension.
- There is an optional filter you can use, looking for 'index' within the pagePathLevel1 (and as you can see, you can chose to use it or not, add more filters, concatenate them, etc.

Also note that the filter & result just return a "query" (just like ActiveModel::Relation), where the execution is done by invoking something on it, like 'each' or 'to_a', etc.

```
class Pageviews
  extend Legato::Model

  metrics :pageviews, :uniquePageviews
  dimensions :pagePathLevel1

  filter(:by_index_in_path_level_1) {|page_path_level1| contains(:pagePathLevel1, 'index')}

  def self.query(profile, start_date, end_date)
    Pageviews.results(profile,
                      :start_date => start_date,
                      :end_date => end_date
    )
    # Just for reference, sorting descending by pageviews is done by:   :sort => '-pageviews'
  end

  def self.query_index(profile, start_date, end_date)
    Pageviews.by_index_in_path_level_1.results(profile,
                                               :start_date => start_date,
                                               :end_date => end_date
    )
  end
end
```

Once this is ready, you can do something like:

```
Pageviews.query(profile, start_date, end_date).each do |result|
    # Just print the pageviews & unique-pageviews, for example
    puts result.try(:pageviews)
    puts result.try(:uniquePageviews)
end
```

Lastly, I recommand that you first explore with [Google Analytics Query Explorer](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/).

I hope you can find this example helpful

Comment: If I wanted to have a filter for the following ga:medium==cpa,ga:medium==cpc,ga:medium==cpm,ga:medium==cpp,ga:medium==cpv,ga:medium==organic,ga:medium==ppc how would I do it?

Comment: I think you should have several filters (one per each condition) and then you need to concatenate them (as you do with scopes, for example). But it has been almost a year since I last dealt with this, so I might be wrong.

Comment: Do you mean like Pageviews.filter1.filter2.etc.results(...)?

Comment: Yes, like with relations

Comment: You answer is really good though, they should put it in the wiki ;)

Comment: https://github.com/tpitale/legato/wiki/Filtering#examples has an example that will work for you Max: `filter :browsers, &lambda {|*browsers| browsers.map {|browser| matches(:broswer, browser)}}` Just replace "browsers" with "mediums", then pass an array of all the mediums you want to use `['cpa', 'cpc', 'cpm' …]`