# Fetch Google Analytics for Model Instances in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-analytics

I am trying to fetch the page views for each instance of our model Campaigns.  After much Googling, I used this post as the basis of my work: http://gistflow.com/posts/398-pageviews-for-posts  I am instead using the updated [Legato](https://github.com/tpitale/legato) gem.

I am having trouble fetching and saving to the database the pageviews for each Campaign.

Here is the modified code working from the gistflow post.

Rake task:

```
namespace :campaigns do
  task :update_page_views => :environment do
    google_analytics = GoogleAnalytics.new

    @campaigns = Campaign.all
    @campaign = Campaign.find(:all)

    @campaigns.each do |campaign|
      page_views = google_analytics.page_views(campaign)
      campaign.update_attribute(:page_views, page_views) if page_views
    end
  end
end
```

Legato model:

```
class GoogleAnalytics
  extend Legato::Model

  metrics :pageviews
  dimensions :page_path

  attr_reader :profile

  def page_views(campaign)
    access_token = GoogleOauth2Installed.access_token
    user = Legato::User.new(access_token) 
    profile = user.profiles.first 
    GoogleAnalytics.results(
        profile,
        :filters => {:page_path.eql => campaign.path},
        :start_date => 5.years.ago.to_date,
        :end_date => Date.today
       ).to_a.first.try(:pageviews)
   end
 end
```

However, I receive an error

```
undefined method `path' for #<Campaign:0xbf334a4>
```

If I change the filter line to:

```
:filters => {:page_path.eql => campaign},
```

then the task runs, but all of the campaigns have the same number of views which matches the total of all of the campaigns.

I played around with the GA Query tool mentioned in [Getting query results with Legato gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082859/getting-query-results-with-legato-gem)
and can get a result I want with:

filters = ga:pagePath==/campaigns/6

However, even if I plug that into the code, the task still results with all of the campaigns having the same number which is the total of campaigns.

I have also looked at this answer [How to pull Google Analytics stats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980456/how-to-pull-google-analytics-stats-in-ruby-on-rails)  but do not have enough reputation yet to ask Severin to explain how to modify the query.

I have looked into the Impressionist gem but would like to make it work with GA as we would like to pull more GA data in the future.

Thanks so much for any help!!

Comment: Filters are not passed to the #results method. They are defined similarly to a named scope. The only options passed to #results are listed here https://github.com/tpitale/legato#other-parameters-can-be-passed-to-a-call-to-results. Filtering is described in more detail here: https://github.com/tpitale/legato/wiki/Filtering. Hope that helps!